# usage of "high end"

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

> I wouldn't think a competitive advantage was price. It's always been **at the higher end** of the market.

'high-end' is **adjective** meaning "of superior quality or sophistication and usually high in price (high–end cameras)"

However, in that sentence, it looks like **noun**. Is it okay in grammar?

and what is the meaning "at the higher end"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyphenated phrase **high-end** is an adjective.  The phrase **at the higher end** is different -- for one thing, no hyphen. The prepositional phrase uses the noun **end** as its last word, and the sentence grammar is fine.

For the specific words:

- adjective: Sony has always been a high-end brand.

Comment: Could you explain the meaning?

Comment: @TINGCHOE You already did, at least for "high-end".  The phrase "at the higher end" has basically the same meaning, but this time "higher" is a stand-alone adjective, and "end" is a normal noun. _The stuff has always been high quality and expensive._